# Can I use my old c#-libraries with WinJS?

Tags: c#, javascript, browser, windows-runtime, winjs

I have some old c#-libraries. Is it possible to use them in a browser application? Can I use them with the JavaScript-Object for example?

Thanks

Comment: How do you mean use them? In browser? Server side? Define "old".

Comment: The library is used by a WPF-Desktop application which is still in use. But it would be fine if the same library could be used in a browser application.

Comment: What kind of "browser application" do you mean? Metro-style app written in JavaScript? Wouldn't it be easier to just write it in C#?

Comment: It would be great if it works in all A-grade Browsers. But I believe that it is not realistic. So where does it work? And is anywhere an example?

Comment: As far as I know, WinJS is not for building browser applications at all. It's for building Metro-style applications using HTML5 and JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably will be able to do that, but it will require some work from you.

To use the library, create a project whose output type is "WinMD file" (either new one, or change the library you have). In this project, all public types and their non-private members have to adhere to some WinRT rules.

For example:

- classes should be sealed (with exceptions for GUI controls)
- custom types may not be generic
- most generic types from the framework may not be used, with the exception of some collection interfaces

Comment: Is there anywhere an example?

Comment: I couldn't find any. There doesn't seem to be much on the internet about WinMD files (yet?).

Comment: Found this post today. It might help http://blendinsider.com/technical/creating-an-html-metro-style-app-that-references-c-and-c-code-2012-04-13/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
WinJS is built on top of WinRT which has a "translating layer" from any (supported) platform language. So you definitely should be able to use any "old" C# libraries in your code written in JavaScript in WinJS.